# show an image on mouse over another image css or jquery option?

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have the following code that works.

HTML

```
<div id="menuContainer">
        <div id="menu3"><a class="thumbnail" href="business_two.html"><img src="images/ncb_integrate_business_one_menu3.jpg" width="126" height="45" />
        <span><img src="images/ncb_integrate_business_drop.png" width="164" /></span></a></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#menu3 { width:126px; height:45px; float:left; }

.thumbnail {
    zoom:1.0;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.thumbnail span {
position:fixed;
    top:150px;
    left:500px;
    width:350px;
    left:-999em;
    z-index:990    
}
.thumbnail:hover {visibility:visible; }
.thumbnail:hover span { left:38%; opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */ }
* html .thumbnail span {position:absolute;}
```

The above works fine, just that when its a  i am guessing it doesnt follow rules of the  its under. In this case the 'menuContainer'. on the computer i am coding on looks fine. But when i see it on an ipad or another screen size, the image that shows on-hover, moves 38% according to the ipad screen size.

I have a `#mainContainer { margin: auto; width: 1000px; overflow:hidden; }`
Can i keep the .thumbnail span within the #mainContainer and not flow out anywhere it likes ?

Thanks a million guys
G

Comment: You've got plenty of options. a) multiple stylesheets depending upon the rendering device; b) CSS calculation of the screen size and thumbnail placement and; c) JS/jQuery calculation of the screen size and thumbnail placement.

Comment: Thanks devlshone, but isnt there a simple enuf solution without complicating the issue further with those alternatives ? I was searching for Jquery solutions but seems like they dont work like floats - they push the divs down instead of floating on top. Thanks.